# Find the regular expressions of the following?Language of odd length and cannot contain length multiple of 3 over ={,}

Tags: theory, automata

Language of odd length and cannot contain length multiple of 3  over
={,}

Answer (score 1):

OK to have an odd length that's not a multiple of 3, we can have a "head" part that generates strings of length 6n, and then a "tail" part that generates strings of length 1 and 5 (but not 7). Any odd number that's not a multiple of 3 can be written as 6n + 1 or 6n + 5 for n >= 0. So, let's get crackin.

```
r = ((a + b)^6)*((a + b) + (a + b)^5)
```

I have used a shorthand notation here which you can omit; basically, `s ^ n` stands for the regular expression `s` repeated `n` times. As long as `n` is a definite number this can be written out, just makes the regular expression a little longer.